# How many times Database is hit in Spring DATA JPA's save(Iterable<S> entities)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following lines of code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/persons",method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<List<Person>> saveUsers(@RequestBody List<Person> persons) {
        persons = (List<Person>) userRepository.save(persons);
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Person>>(persons, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And here is the repository:

```
@Transactional
public interface UserRepository  extends UserBaseRepository<User> { 
}

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface UserBaseRepository<T extends User> extends CrudRepository<T, Long> {
    public T findByEmail(String email);
}
```

It runs fine. While running the code I see the following logs.

```
Hibernate: insert into user (email, firstname, lastname, user_type) values (?, ?, ?, 'Person')
Hibernate: insert into user (email, firstname, lastname, user_type) values (?, ?, ?, 'Person')
Hibernate: insert into user (email, firstname, lastname, user_type) values (?, ?, ?, 'Person')
Hibernate: insert into user (email, firstname, lastname, user_type) values (?, ?, ?, 'Person')
```

It seems that, the DataBase is hit 4 times. I have seen the implementation of save(iterable e) method, where the for loop is run to save each entity. So, my questions is:

1. is the DB hit 4 times ?
2. if so, then can it be done in 1 db hit (using Spring Data JPA) ? By doing so, will it give a performance boost in case of inserting a large number of records ?

Comment: Yes, you are hitting db 4 times. If you are working with highload applications, good idea will be to use hibernate batch or ... make your own batch opertation using multithreading.

Comment: It depends what you mean by hitting the database 4 times - you have probably have 4 inserts on the one connection, where the real cost is likely creating the connection

Comment: @farrellmr : I also think the same.
So, is the above solution of inserting records more effective than JDBC's preparedStatement's addBatch() and executebatch() from performance point of view ?

Comment: It depends on how many inserts you are expecting in a batch - i mean if the number is less than 10, the i would leave as is. Otherwise you need to right a custom query. Difference with say JDBC or custom query is spring-data is generating inserts for you, so you are delagating control

Comment: I think, by custom query, you mean @Query annotation, but, then also, will it take lesser time to insert than PreparedStatement's batch if the number of records to be inserted are higher like 50 to 100 ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are querying the data four times.

You can have the insertion done in one batch statement by implementing [Hibernate Batching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch). In particular, take a look at performing [batch inserts](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch-session-batch-insert). Using batch inserts, you must control the session manually by making explicit calls to the `flush()` and `clear()` methods in the session.

Also, consider setting the appropriate [Hibernate Batching Properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-batch) such as the batch size (default 5), and if applicable, permission for Hibernate to re-order insertions and updates before constructing the batch statements:

```
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 25
hibernate.order_inserts = true
hibernate.order_updates = true
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but the result was the same.
`final List<T> savedEntities = new ArrayList<T>(entities.size());
  int i = 0;
  for (T t : entities) {
   savedEntities.add(persistOrMerge(t));
   i++;
   if (i % batchSize == 0) {
    // Flush a batch of inserts and release memory.
    entityManager.flush();
    entityManager.clear();
   }
  }
  return savedEntities;
 }
 private <T extends User> T persistOrMerge(T t) {
    if (t.getId() == 0) {
      entityManager.persist(t);
      return t;
    } else {
      return entityManager.merge(t);
    }
 }`

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs on Hibernate Batching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch):

> Hibernate disables insert batching at the JDBC level transparently if
>   you use an identity identifier generator.

So, if `Person` is using an `Identity` generator (as opposed to the `Sequence` generator or `TABLE` generator) batching won't take place. See [this section](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#best-practices-mapping-identifiers) for more details on why that is so.